# Why no compilation error for space between the dot when accesing fields and methods?

Tags: java

I accidentally had a space between the dot and field name when accessing the field of a class, example: https://ideone.com/63RuFV

```
class Dog{
String name;

    public Dog(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

...

Dog d = new Dog("Fido");
System.out.println(d. name);
d. print();
```

I'm surprised there wasn't any error. I always assumed you couldn't have any space.

Comment: Why would there be a compilation error for an extra space?

Comment: `System . out . println ("Works too");` - white space isn't significant in a lot of cases.

Comment: Whitespaces may appear between any token.

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: It's usual to break long concatenations after the dot. The ; finishes a line.

Comment: I always had a preconceived notion that there shouldn't be any back from when first learn Java. Was it always like this or was introduced newer versions of Java?

Comment: People often add newlines after `.` on long chained calls (often streams)

Comment: Because it isn't an error. It was always like this.

Comment: Sometimes I wish those were compiler errors...

Comment: @JuanMendes Well, I often see people put the newlines *before* `.`. That's what I prefer as well.

Comment: @mcemperor sure... before, after, the point is that there are common patterns that add space around dots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets quote the [java language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of tokens, using the following three lexical translation steps, which are applied in turn: ...
>
> A translation of the stream of input characters and line terminators resulting from step 2 into a sequence of input elements (§3.5) which, after white space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) are discarded, comprise the tokens (§3.5) that are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar

The key point here: *white space and comments are discarded*.

In other words, since day one, Java is pretty lenient about where you place white space characters. Or how many of them, or which one.

Comment: It is actually found twice in the specs: in both § 2.2 and § 3.2.

Comment: @MCEmperor Honestly, I am not sure. 2.2 only *mentions* whitespaces, it doesn't say that they shall be ignored! And you see: chapter 2 is about the *grammar*. That one just says "these are the elements to be found in java source code". chapter 3 is about lexical processing (giving meaning to source), it is *there* where the meaning of whitespaces (they dont have any real meaning) is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a free form language that allows spaces and indent as required.

Comment: Python lets you put spaces before or after the dot too. Python assigns meaning to line breaks and indentation that Java doesn't, but it doesn't assign any meaning to whitespace here.

Comment: That is correct. print(string. isupper()) works! thanks